# ruby array subrange when that range is a variable

Tags: arrays, ruby

Is it possible to apply a sub range to an array in ruby like this:

```
 > array = [4, 3, 2, 1]
 > array[0...2]
=> [4, 3]
```

if the `[0...2]` is stored in a variable?  I can't seem to get a syntax to give me what I want.  What replaces the `<?>` in the following, if anything?

```
 > array = [4, 3, 2, 1]
 > range = [0...2]
 > array<?>
=> [4, 3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sure! Do this way:

```
array = [4, 3, 2, 1]
exclusive_range = [0...2] # Will get 0th and 1st element of the array
inclusive_range = [0..2] # Will get 0th, 1st and 2nd element of the array
array[exclusive_range.first]
# => [4, 3]
array[inclusive_range.first] 
# => [4, 3, 2]
```

If you want to avoid `.first` call, you can put your range in a variable (Not in an array):

```
range = 0...2
array[range]
# => [4, 3]
```

Comment: Very interesting!  Why must we call first on it?

Comment: Because your range (`0...2`) is the first element of `exclusive_range` array.

Comment: Look at my updated answer, that way if you define the range just as a variable not in an array, then you don't need to call: `range.first`. Let me know if you any other question.

Comment: @JakeSmith: Because your `range` variable does not point to a `Range` object, it points to an `Array` object with a single element which is a `Range` object. Square brackets `[]` denote an `Array` literal. You could fix this by assigning a `Range` to the `range` variable instead of an `Array` of `Range`s.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `(0..2).size #=> 3`. If you want to return `[4,3]` you want:

```
range = 0..1
```

You could use it like this:

```
array[range]           #=> [4, 3]
```

or like this:

```
array.values_at *range #=> [4, 3]
```